# Htaccess redirect a page with a query string hosted on a temporary IP address?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site that was temporarily set up as `111.222.333.444/~mysite` because the real URL was not ready. `111.222.333.444/~mysite/?page_id=123` was a valid page on that site. My site is live now. I no longer want or need to use `111.222.333.444/~mysite` to access the site.

However Google has indexed a search for a term on page `?page_id=123` as `111.222.333.444/~mysite/?page_id=123`. But `?page_id=123` no longer exists. It's now on a new page, and I want to redirect Google's link to `www.example.com/newpage`

The closest I have come to implemeting this redirect is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^111\222\.333\.444$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^\?page_id=123$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^~mysite/$ //www.example.com/newpage [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

But this doesn't work, and gives me an internal server error.

I have also tried:

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=195 /newpage
```

But that had no effect.  Can anyone suggest how to do this? I don't have a problem redirecting single pages, but the temporary/alternate URL with the IP address is throwing me.

Comment: Redirecting will keep the old URL alive. I would not do this. I would just let the page 404. Google will eventually remove it from the index and find your correct page.

Comment: Fair point, but alas I have a client who does not want it to 404! The client is always right :-) Besides, Im puzzled I cant seem to get such an apparently simple redirect working - it isnt hard for the same url, but something is odd about using the ip address.

Comment: Silly silly client! ;-) You have two of our very best below so I am sure you will be able to redirect the way you want soon. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

The [mod_alias documenation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) states in the top section that it doesn't support redirects based on query strings.  You are not going to be able to get a `Redirect 301` rule to work.

I see a couple problems with your rewrite rule:

1. You are missing a period (`.`) in your ip address rule.
2. The question mark (`?`) is not included in the query string so `\?` should not be part of your `QUERY_STRING` rule.
3. mod_rewrite doesn't support protocol relative redirect URLs.   Your new URL can't start with `//`.   You need to start it with `http://` or `https://` [unless you do a bunch of fancy hocus pocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372594/preserve-http-https-protocol-in-htaccess-redirects).

Also:

- I don't think you need the no case (`[NC]`) flag, so I would omit it.
- I don't think you need the no escape (`[NE]`) flag, so I would omit it.
- If your new site doesn't use a `page_id=123` query string at all, you could remove the requirement that it has to be on the IP address.
- Similarly, I would omit the `~mysite` part of the rule.    Just base the redirect  on the the query string, not on the folder it is in.

I would try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^page_id=123$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com/newpage?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You'll need a `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (or use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+) to remove the query string from the redirected URL. Otherwise, mod_rewrite passes the query string through unaltered, which would result in a redirect loop. +1

Comment: Edited in the `?` based on w3dk's suggestion